# Reducer is not defined when compiling the code

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reduce

Below is the code which is incorrect in the line 8

```
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import reducer from "./Reducer/Combine";

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)

export default store;
```

below code is from the combine folder

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import tablereducer from "./tablereducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    tablereducer: tablereducer
})

export default reducer;
```

Is there any new import module to use reducer?

Comment: Had you combine multiple reducers?

Comment: May you share code in ./Reducer/Combine?

Comment: @AndreySmolko below is the combine folder code

**import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import tablereducer from "./tablereducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    tablereducer: tablereducer
})

export default reducer;**

Comment: @Asifvora yes bro i used combine reducers

Comment: You can do this way `composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))`.